# Resetting following an animation

Tags: jquery

I have the [following animation](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/9TvRU/) configured to fade and slide a block into view on "mouseover", only to fadeout and slide it away again on "mouseout". However, if I move the mouse back over the container DIV again the same animation proceeds but starting from the wrong position. How do I get it to reset back to the starting position? If possible, I'd like to avoid having to add another animation to move it back to the original position.

```
$(".box").css("opacity",0);
    $(".container").mouseover(function () {
        $(".box").stop(true, true).animate({top:99, opacity: 1},150);
    });
    $(".container").mouseout(function () {
        $(".box").stop(true, true).animate({top:59, opacity: 0},150);
    });
```

Comment: You're changing the CSS properties, and you need to change them back to the original state, like in [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9TvRU/6/) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset it to whatever the top value originally was while it's hidden before you start your first animation.  I put the value `("top", 50)` in the example, but you can fill in the actual starting value you want:

```
$(".box").css("opacity",0);
$(".container").mouseover(function () {
    $(".box").stop(true, true).css("top", 50).animate({top:99, opacity: 1},150);
});
$(".container").mouseout(function () {
    $(".box").stop(true, true).animate({top:59, opacity: 0},150);
});
```